# Is it possible to save a NSManagedObjectModel?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I have the following requirement: create and populate a SQLite database with data from a .xml file, this file can have a different structure any time so I cannot create the `NSManagedObjectModel` with Xcode, it must be at runtime. I've successfully created a `NSManagedObjectModel` programmatically, created the persistent store and populated the sqlite file with data from the .xml . However, the next time I use the app the persistent store is not compatible with the `NSManagedObjectModel` (I don't want to recreate the Model every time I run the app, just the first time). Is there any way to save the model I created programmatically and load it the next time it is needed? All I can see in the examples are models being loaded from the `NSBundle`.

Comment: If you are going to allow your model/schema to change based on the data it receives, you will need some really tight migration code, or make sure that any changes to the model are compatible with light-weight migration.  If any of that is new to you, then you really need to read the Core Data documentation about migrations: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to save the model I created programmatically and load it the next time it is needed?

Yes. `NSManagedObjectModel` conforms to `NSCoding`, which means that you can easily convert it to/from `NSData`, and saving and reading `NSData` is easy.

To save a model:

```
NSString *modelPath = // path where you want to save
NSData *modelData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.managedObjectModel];
[modelData writeToFile:modelPath atomically:YES];
```

To read a saved model:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:modelPath]) {
    NSData *savedModelData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:modelPath];
    NSManagedObjectModel *savedModel = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedModelData];
}
```

Comment: Genius, it is working now! You saved me hours (maybe days) of hard work. Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, although maybe unsurprisingly, the archive this technique produces is identical to the .mom file Xcode generates. The keyed unarchiver and `-[NSManagedObjectModel initWithContentsOfURL:]` are interchangeable. However, this is not documented, so should not be relied upon.

Comment: Although I have not confirmed this, I would strongly urge that anyone saving a model with this undocumented method open the model in Xcode make minor edit then save it out from Xcode and the ship that file.  Apple does a lot of hashing and IDing on files like d models and Xcode datamodel editor may leave a critical finger print on its files you may need latter.

Comment: @TechZen None of this is undocumented. `NSManagedObjectModel` conforms to `NSCoding`, and `NSKeyedArchiver` works on classes that conform to that protocol. That's all completely documented. Also, `NSManagedObjectModel` together with classes like `NSEntityDescription` and `NSPropertyDescription` have a full set of methods to create a managed object model in code. There's literally nothing you can do in Xcode here that can't be done in code with documented methods.

Comment: @TomHarrington - You might be correct, at present, but I did look into this years ago, and I distinctly recall encountering issues although at this remove I do not recall the details. At some point, you couldn't save the model save from the editor, but again, that could have been 5+ years ago or more now. Opening it in the data model model editor at some point seems a reasonable precaution... but then I always expect things to explode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are saying that the data in the xml file is changing each time or what. It sounds like you are referring to the data, not the data model. I can't answer specifically, but I would take the approach as follows.

If the data in the xml file is structured the same or close to the same each time, I would create a data model to match that.

Then I would write some sort of parser class that would read the xml and parse it into the Core Data data store according to you "ManagedObjectModel" or data model.

I have seen the error you are talking about when you change the datastore outside of Core Data. You need to let Core Data handle all the reading and writing to the data store or else Core Data will tell you basically that "Your Persistent Store was created or altered by something other than your ManagedObjectModel".  I think this is what is happening.

I know I am not using the terminology exactly as Core Data puts it, but Core Data is confusing and I'm trying to convey the message and understanding.

I would also look in to using MagicalRecord. It *Drastically* makes Core Data easier to work with and there is a great tutorial on www.raywenderlich.com which you can find [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/56879/magicalrecord-tutorial-ios)

I really hope this helps you out some. If not, please post some sample code or maybe an example of that xml you are referring to.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The app I’m developing should be capable to load a .xml file, construct the Data Model (just in the initial setup) and populate the Database. The ultimate purpose of the app is that it should be able to work with data that does know (neither the structure of the data) and it is downloaded at runtime. Thanks to Tom Harrington (answer below) I could save the model created in the initial setup, and now everything is working fine